# Partial View is not reloading after an update

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

***Question Background:***

I have a simple cart system. The main 'Cart' view renders a 'PartialView' that displays a table of Items the users has in their shopping cart.

***The issue:***

Currently when a user updates the item quantities in their cart they click on the 'Update Cart' Button which updates the cart objects on its associated controller then re-renders the partial view with the new quanitites. **The issue is the re-render is not displaying the item details once updated**

**1. User adds items to their cart:**

[image]

**2. User updates the first item in the cart from a quantity of '2' items to '3':**

Note that the 'total' has been updated but the table has not.

[image]

***Code:***

This is the main `ViewCartContents.cshtml` view that contains the `_ViewCartContents.cshtml` partial view.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Cart</h2>
    @Html.Partial("_ViewCartContents")
</div>

<div class="container">
       @Html.ActionLink("PayPal", "Index", "PayPalTest")
       @Html.ActionLink("Card Payment", "ShippingDetails", "Checkout")
</div>
```

The Partial View `_ViewCartContents.cshtml`:

```
<div id="tableContainer">
<div id="divTest" class="row">
    <table id="Table1" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">id</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><b>Item</b></td>
                <td><b>Brand</b></td>
                <td><b>Unit Price</b></td>
                <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block updateCart" type="button" value="Update Cart" />
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Total: £@ViewBag.Total</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var AddRows = function (productId, productImage, productName, productBrand, productPrice, productQty) {

        var button = '<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block deleteItem" type="button" value="Remove"/>';
        var image = '<img src="/Images/' + productImage + '" class="productCartImage"/>';
        var selectors = '<input id="demo1" type="text" value="' + productQty + '" name="demo1">'

        var $html = $('<tr class="item">' +
        '<td class="prodId" style="display:none;">' + productId + '</td>' +
        '<td class="prodImage">' + image + '</td>' +
        '<td class="prodName">' + productName + '</td>' +
        '<td class="prodBrand">' + productBrand + '</td>' +
        '<td class="prodPrice">' + productPrice + '</td>' +
        '<td class="prodQty">' + selectors + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + button + '</td>' +
        '</tr>');

        $('#Table1 > tbody:last').append($html);

    };
</script>



@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
    <script>
        var cartItemId = '@cartItem.CartItemId'
        var cartImage = '@cartItem.CartItemImage';
        var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
        var cartBrand = '@cartItem.CartItemBrand';
        var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
        var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

        AddRows(cartItemId, cartImage, cartItemName, cartBrand, cartItemPrice, cartItemCartItemQty)

    </script>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".deleteItem").click(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $text = $row.find(".prodId").text();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("RemoveCartItem")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "id": $text
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>

    $("input[name='demo1']").TouchSpin({
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".updateCart").click(function () {

        $("tr.item").each(function () {

            var $prodId = $(this).find("td.prodId").html();
            var $prodQty = $(this).find("input").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateAllCartItems")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    "id": $prodId,
                    "qty": $prodQty
                },
                success: function (partialView) {
                    $('#tableContainer').html(partialView);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

The `UpdateAllCartItems` method on the `Cart Controller`:

During debug I can confirm that the 'CartItems' object properties ***do*** have the correct updated item quantities.

```
 public ActionResult UpdateAllCartItems(string id, string qty)
    {
        CartItems = (List<CartItem>)Session["Cart"];

        foreach(var item in CartItems)
        {
            if (item.CartItemId == Convert.ToInt32(id))
            {
                item.CartItemQty = qty;
            }
        }

         CartItems = (List<CartItem>)Session["Cart"];

        ViewBag.Data = CartItems;

        ViewBag.Total = CalculateCartTotal(CartItems);

        Session["Cart"] = CartItems;

        return PartialView("_ViewCartContents", ViewBag);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your partial view renders not html with data but JavaScript code
which should be evaluated on the browser side.

In the beginning when entire page is requested by browser,
e.g. when you just opening the page in it,
MVC will render entire HTML and then return it as one response.
After that browser receives data from server, renders html and evaluate javascript.
That why you see cart details table rendered before clicking update cart button.

When user clicks update cart button,
javascript send AJAX request to server
server rendrer partial view which not contain the actual html (representation of data)
but html template and javascript (code to produce the presentation of data)

When the browser receives that response, you just
put it AS text into #tableContainer

```
success: function (partialView) {
  $('#tableContainer').html(partialView);
}
```

That is why you see correct Total (which was enclosed in proper place in template)
but not see the rest of your data.

To avoid this behavior you may follow two approaches:

1. Compose all html on server side in partial view (using Razor instead of javascript)
2. Send only Data (json/xml) to the client and then using JavaScript construct the UI

Answer (score 0):

Add div with id="tableContainer" html in main view(ViewCartContents.cshtml) 
you added it in partial view so after returning by update method it cant find .